# Cannot translate language in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, transactions, flutter-easy-localization

I'm using [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) in my app. I have changed the language setting from English to Chinese, but app still displays English.

This is my project directory:

[image]

**main.dart**

```
 runApp(EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('zh-CN', 'CN')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      child: const App(),
    )
```

**zh-CN.json**

```
"hello": "你好",
```

**widget.dart**

```
Text('hello'.tr());
```

Is it because the languageCode and countryCode wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create folder and add translation files like this

assets
└── translations
    ├── {languageCode}.{ext}                  //only language code
    └── {languageCode}-{countryCode}.{ext}    //or full locale code

Example:

assets
└── translations
    ├── en.json
    └── en-US.json 

Declare your assets localization directory in pubspec.yaml:

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/translations/
```

Comment: how about for chinese language?

Comment: maybe zh - should always render as Traditional Chinese, this is what "traditional" means.
Different countries have their own system of Simplified Chinese, and so should be a country based system. (e.g. zh-CN, zh-SG, overriding zh)

Comment: so how to fix ? I'm lost

Comment: @Hoo can you please share the content of your json files?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `Locale(this._languageCode, [this._countryCode,])`, the value `'zh-CN'` is not supported for the parameter `_languageCode`.

***The subtag values are *case sensitive* and must be one of the valid subtags according to CLDR supplemental data:

[language](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/validity/language.xml),

[region](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/validity/region.xml).***

########## Solution #########
Try replacing:-

`supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('zh-CN', 'CN')],`

with

`supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('zh', 'CN')],`

If this is not meeting your requirements, you can consider looking for an alternate language code which is supported from this link : [language](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/validity/language.xml)

Hope this solves your problem.